# vue js increase the value with mousedown

Tags: javascript, vue.js

With this code, the pos_number only increases by one when the mouse is held down. How to make a button that will increase the value as long as the mouse is held down?

```
<button
  @mousedown="setValue({name: 'robotx_increase',value: (robotx_increase = 'true'),});robotx_pos_number ++ "
  @mouseup="setValue({name: 'robotx_increase',value: (robotx_increase = 'false'),})">
</button>

data() {
    return {
      robotx_pos_number: 0
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

You could call a function like 'startAdding()' on the mousedown event,  which uses the setInterval method that keeps adding 1 to 'robotx_pos_number' every x milliseconds. This interval should then be cleared with the mouseup event.